# Nativescript - prompt alert in webview

Tags: ios, angular, mobile, webview, nativescript

How to handle JavaScript alert/confirm pop up dialog in WebView for iOS platform? There is nothing happen when alert is triggered.

I have set following code inside webview loadstartedEvent, but still fail to see the alert window:

```
webview.ios.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On iOS, `WKWebView` do not handle JavaScript alert / confirm dialogs by default. The developer has to handle himself by implementing the [WKUIDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkuidelegate?language=objc) which should be similar to [WKNavigationDelegate](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/master/tns-core-modules/ui/web-view/web-view.ios.ts#L5) implementation.

Use the `webViewRunJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessageInitiatedByFrameCompletionHandler` callback to show alert dialog.

Comment: I'm so sorry i still nerd on native code. How to write the callback in NS in order to display the dialog?

Comment: Really appreciate for giving instruction, i have find out the way to call the handler and it is works now! Thanks alot!

Comment: @Manoj : Could you please share how you handle javascript alert/ confirm dialog by implementing WKUIDelegate. if possible share some code so I can understand it.

Comment: Refer the core framework code for examples of implementing [delegate](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/master/packages/core/ui/web-view/index.ios.ts#L9), you will have to implement WKUIDelegate in similar fashion by extending or overriding the component.